# Сборка файлов C#

Tags: c#, makefile

У меня имеется несколько `.cs` файлов и `Makefile.win`, который выглядит так:

```
makefile : Server.exe Client.exe

Server.exe : Server.cs  
    csc Server.cs

Client.exe : Client.cs RemoteTestService.dll  
    csc /r:RemoteTestService.dll Client.cs

RemoteTestService.dll: TestService.cs  
    csc /out:RemoteTestService.dll /t:library TestService.cs
```

Как все это собрать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм.

```
 make -f Makefile.win makefile
 или
 make -f Makefile.win Server.exe
 make -f Makefile.win Client.exe
```